# MutableStateflow Value Vs Update vs Emit

Tags: android, kotlin, setter, kotlin-stateflow

Let say I have a [MutableStateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/index.html) variable. What is the main differences and usage of the three cases

```
mutable.value = 1
mutable.emit(2)
mutable.update {3}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`emit()` is nothing but a `suspend` function which internally uses the `mutable.value = newValue`.

The `update {}`  is used for atomic updates i.e. for managing/handling concurrent operations which internally uses `compareAndSet` to (obviously) compare the values & see if the previous value has changed or not (say via some other Thread).

You can read more about `update {}` here:
https://medium.com/geekculture/atomic-updates-with-mutablestateflow-dc0331724405