# Can we replace all usages of StateFlow.value with StateFlow.update?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

Reading the following articles,

- [MutableStateflow Value Vs Update vs Emit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72224263/9636037)
- https://medium.com/geekculture/atomic-updates-with-mutablestateflow-dc0331724405
- https://proandroiddev.com/make-sure-to-update-your-stateflow-safely-in-kotlin-9ad023db12ba
- https://www.droidcon.com/2021/08/25/make-sure-to-update-your-stateflow-safely-in-kotlin/

I can understand that we can use [stateflow update()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/update.html) to update the value atomically.
This is useful when the updated value has a `copy()` or some long-running calculations. (API call, room data fetch, etc.)

My question is can we completely **replace all the usages of `stateflow.value`** using `update()` or is there any use-case where `.value` is the better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn’t use it when it’s not necessary for the logic you want, because it’s more code and less performant. Also, if you put long-running suspend functions in there, then other coroutines that want to update it and are also using `update` will have to wait. If this doesn’t matter to your logic, you’ll be making everything slower.

I can't think of any reason to use it except when the new value must be dependent on the immediately previous value.